# Using while loops to determine a text value from an enumerated file

Tags: python

## THE ERROR IS "Cannot assign to function call"

So I have written a code that with an input of:

```
 To BE or NoT tO be
```

will return:

```
 1,2,3,4,1,2
```

this is what I will refer to as "compressed".
Now I need to take that output and turn it back into the input (case does not matter) The code I have written (below) will not function when I input 2 and I do not understand why. Please help open to suggestions. I , however, struggle with the compression functions built into python such as zlib or gzip.

```
floop = 0
while floop ==0:
choice = int(input("Press 1 to compress a text and 2 to decode a text:"))
if choice == 1:
    tfile = int(input("Press:\n 1 to compress the File  \n 2 to start again:"))
    if tfile ==1:
        print("Compressing file 1")
        file1 = open("File1.txt","r")
        sent = file1.readlines()
        sent = str(sent)

        splitsent = sent.lower().split()#Lowers the case and splits the sentence
        dl = [0]
        #Defines the DL variable
        for count , v in enumerate (splitsent):
        #Enumerates the splitsent list
            if splitsent.count(v) < 2:
            #Cycles through the splitsent list apending dl
               dl.append(max(dl) +1) #Defines the unique variable set 
            else:
               dl.append(splitsent.index(v) +1)
    #Adds the remainding values to the dl list
        dl.remove(0)#Removes the starting zero
        print(sent, "\n",dl)#Prints the output
        ec = open("Encoded.txt","w")
        dl = str(dl)
        ec.write(dl)
        ec.close()
    elif tfile == 2:
        print("Back to the beginning")
    else:
        print ("Invalid input")
elif choice == 2:
    file1 = open("File1.txt","r")
    sent = file1.readlines()
    sent = str(sent).lower().split()
    u=0
    
    ofile = open("Encoded.txt","r")
    decode = ofile.readlines()
    decode = str(decode).split()
    u = 0
    decode(0) = sent(0)
    while u < len(decode):
        u=u+1
        decode(u) = sent(u)
```

I would greatly appreciate the assistance or returning an output of text when the input of 2 is done so.

## EDIT

This is the input file (File1.txt)

```
Karen spent every waking moment planning the perfect life. Her mind soaked up luxury, sun and freedom. She could almost taste her homemade spaghetti sauce simmering on the stove in her quiet apartment. The putrid odor of another inmate slapped Karen back to reality. Only nine thousand days to go.
```

and this is the Encoded.txt file:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 10, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 7, 27, 28, 10, 29, 30, 7, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 43, 49]
```

Comment: If your problem is only with "choice 2", then your code example should omit "choice 1" code.

Comment: Sorry, I included it for reference as to how I enumerated my list, though chunky it works. I thought maybe it would further the understanding? @cwallenpoole

Comment: "The code I have written will not function" is not a clear problem statement. Please tell us what you *expect* and what *actually happens*, along with *concise example code*.

Comment: @HenryKeiter Sorry. I would like my code to give an output of a text file that would be in words rather than the input which is an enumerated list

Comment: I think you need to use `dict` for mapping indexes to words, also use `json` module to save and load from files

Comment: @ahmed I'm still trying to work around an error with assigning the function to call that appears before the decode(u) line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to assign to a function call:

```
decode(0) = sent(0)
```

You might mean

```
# notice changing ( to [, as you are doing decode(0) = as well as decode(u) =
decode[u] = sent[u]
```

You also have:

```
 while < len(decode):
```

Which is syntactically incorrect. I believe you mean:

```
 while u < len(decode):
```

However it would be better to say:

```
l = len(decode)
while u < l:
```

It sounds like your eventual target is:

```
# A target output value.
output = []
while u < l:
   key = sent[u]
   # append the value found at the index of sent
   output.append(decode[key])
```

Or better yet:

```
output = [decode[val] for val in sent]
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be what I am searching for. However I am receiving an error : Cannot assign to function call and the red box infront of decode(u)? How would I fix this?

Comment: @AshleyPeterThomas `cannot assign to function call` means that you've got a function call (such as `decode(u)`) on the left side of an equals sign. In other words, the exact problem this answer is solving, except three lines later.

Comment: @HenryKeiter  I forgot the double equals sign! Got it now!

Comment: But I do need some assistance with a callable error on the same line